# Is there a cross-browser way to check for IPv6-only hosts from within wpad.dat?

Tags: ipv6, wpad.dat

I'm starting to roll out IPv6 across our network and I would like a way to tell from within wpad.dat if a given host/url is IPv6-only (like ipv6.google.com).  The reason that I ask is because our proxy server (Astaro Security Gateway v7) is IPv4-only and returns an error page if you try and access an IPv6-only host through it.  The next version of our proxy server supports IPv6 but it may be a while before we are able to upgrade.

Most of our users are using Internet Explorer - our standard is IE7 but there are quite a few people still using IE6 and there are also a lot of people using Firefox, Chrome, and Safari, and who knows what else.

Answer (score 1):

wpad.dat gives a javascript function. You will have to look up the IPv6-support for functions like isInNet or their ipv6-capable complements.

Comment: That's the point of the question.... I've googled and found any number of ipv6-capable functions, but they all seemed to be browser-specific.  I was hoping that someone knew of something that worked for more than one browser, at least for FF and IE.

Comment: It's not working with firefox 9.0 for me when I'm using: return "PROXY [::1]:3128"; In m'y wpad.dat, only ipv4 seems to work fine.
But (my proxy) squid > convert ipv4 request to ipv6 request when IPv6 is available. The future is not yet ready.